# Getting data from a Spinner (Android Studio)

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to get the data from three spinners, ready to POST it. I'm having trouble with a load of errors with my code that I don't understand...I'm new to Java/Android. I've looked around and the code I'm using comes from another Stackoverflow answer but it does work:

```
//Spinner data
        final Spinner findViewById(R.id.spinner_house);
        String spinner_house_data = spinner_house.getSelectedItem().toString();

        final Spinner findViewById(R.id.spinner_year);
        String spinner_year_data = spinner_year.getSelectedItem().toString();

        final Spinner spinner_name = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_name);
        String spinner_name_data = spinner_name.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

The specific errors are:

- `(R.id.spinner_house);` *Not a statement*
- `findViewById(R.id.spinner_year);` *Not a statement*

Thanks for any help, as I say I'm new to Android and it's all a bit confusing! (This JSON request would take 5 lines of jQuery!)

Comment: very ugly programming error! :P you need to add the variable name and the cast.  final Spinner spinner_house = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_house);

Comment: If I do that I get an error telling me the variable is already declared! What variable am I declaring here? The one where the string is placed?

Comment: ok check my answer! but check your code, what variables are declared! :)

Comment: Ok, spinner_house is the name of the spinner (object). spinner_house_data is the variable for the string to be placed in. :)

Comment: Previously, the spinner_house and spinner_year objects have been populated. spinner_name hasn't been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
 final Spinner spinner_house = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_house);
    String spinner_house_data = spinner_house.getSelectedItem().toString();

    final Spinner spinner_year = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_year);
    String spinner_year_data = spinner_year.getSelectedItem().toString();

    final Spinner spinner_name = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_name);
    String spinner_name_data = spinner_name.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

but if your variables have been already declared:

```
spinner_house = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_house);
spinner_house_data = spinner_house.getSelectedItem().toString();

spinner_year = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_year);
spinner_year_data = spinner_year.getSelectedItem().toString();

spinner_name = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_name);
spinner_name_data = spinner_name.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify a variable name for the first 2 spinners.
The code for the third spinner seems good.

Here's what you should have:

> ```
>     final Spinner spinner_house = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_house);
>     String spinner_house_data = spinner_house.getSelectedItem().toString();
>
>     final Spinner spinner_year = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_year);
>     String spinner_year_data = spinner_year.getSelectedItem().toString();
>
>     final Spinner spinner_name = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_name);
>     String spinner_name_data = spinner_name.getSelectedItem().toString();
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! If I do that, I get an error telling me the 'variable is already defined in the scope'.

Comment: That means one of these variables (spinner_house, spinner_house_data, spinner_year, spinner_year_data, spinner_name, spinner_name_data) is already used in another part of your code, close to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of listeners.

So each spinner keeps track of what is selected in member variables.

```
   String s1Value;

   s1.setAdapter(adapter);

   s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(
                        AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   s1Value = adapter.get(position);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                   s1Value = "";
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First add permission in android manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2) add in gradle.build

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

3) Create layout with spinner

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />
```

4) And then next write code in src with class MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String URL="YOUR URL HERE";
        JSONArray Cities=null;
        ArrayList<Cities> citiesList =new ArrayList<Cities>(); Spinner citiesspinner;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            new JSONAsyncTask().execute();

        }

private class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {

  private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
      this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
      this.dialog.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... urls) {
      try {

          //------------------>>
          HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(URL);
          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

          // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
          int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

          if (status == 200) {
              HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
              String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


              JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
               Cities = jsono.getJSONArray("Cities");
              return Cities;
          }


      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (JSONException e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return Cities;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
      dialog.dismiss();
      System.out.println(result);

      for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject c = null;
          try {
              Cities cities=new Cities();
              c = result.getJSONObject(i);
              cities.setId(c.getString("CityID"));
              cities.setCityname(c.getString("CityName"));
              citiesList.add(cities);
          } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

      }

      citiesspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
      citiesspinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), citiesList));

      citiesspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
              // your code here

              String value=citiesList.get(position).getCityname();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
              // your code here
          }
      });
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
final Spinner findViewById(R.id.spinner_house);
```

Use this:

```
final Spinner spinner_house= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_house);
```

Instead of:

```
final Spinner findViewById(R.id.spinner_year);
```

Usse this:

```
final Spinner spinner_year= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_year);
```